# Haskell - Elapsed days between two dates

Tags: haskell

I'm working on a small haskell program that I gave the name the "Haskel-dator", hahaha....anyway, heres my current progress on the code for it, and the run-time errors that followed:

**Code**

```
data Date = Date Int Int Int 
type Date = (Int,Int,Int)  

sum :: Int -> Int -> Int 
sum x y | let x - y = z 
        | where z > 0

diff :: Date -> Date -> Int   -- Difference between the two dates 
diff (a,b,c) (x,y,z) = if a < x && b < y && c < z   
        then do sum
        else return 0
```

**Errors**
*ERROR "myprogram.hs": - Multiple declarations of type constructor "Date"
*

Basically, I want my program to have the following assumptions:

- Definition **type Date = (Int,Int,Int)** where the tuple (1,2,2010) denotes 1st Feb 2010.
- The first argument (date) should be earlier than the second argument (date). If not, return 0.
- Assume that dates are correctly formatted. For instance, there is no need to check for invalid dates like (32,13,2010).
- Leap years *must* be taken into account.

I want my program to achieve an output that should look something like this:

**Example Output**
diff (1,1,2010) (10,1,2010) => 9 
diff (2,2,2011) (2,2,2012) => 365 
diff (28,2,2012) (1,3,2012) => 2

Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the immediate error is pretty much self-explanatory: You declared `Date` twice, once as a new datatype `Date Int Int Int`, and once as `(Int, Int, Int)`. It can't be both. Pick one.

Neither of the functions you declared are valid syntax, and I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to say with them. `do` and `return` don't do what you think they do. Start with [LYAH](http://learnyouahaskell.com/)

Comment: Besides the problem stated above, your `sum` function makes no sense. (It will clash with the already defined `sum` function as well, so you should name it something different). I think the simplest way to do this would be to convert each date to an amount of days since some arbitrary day, find the difference, then convert back to a date.

Comment: @MarkWhitfield, thanks for pointing out the double declaration on "Date", I sort of figured that something was wrong there. Thanks for the like to LYAH. Looking it up now.

Answer (score 6):

You should look at the standard `time` package.

The [diffDays](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v%3AdiffDays) function is exactly what you want. It returns the number of days between two dates.

```
diffDays :: Day -> Day -> Integer
```

The dates are defines with as [Day](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#t:Day).

Day instances can be build by using the [fromGregorian](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:fromGregorian) function.

The complete example can be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.4.2/docs/Data-Time-Calendar.html#v:fromGregorian).

Keep in mind that calculating the number of days between two dates correctly is a very complex task.